# What project is good for a total beginner

Tags: tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For a seasoned programmer Arduino or something else?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24343/for-a-seasoned-programmer-arduino-or-something-else)

I am an advanced systems programmer, y have 8 years experience programming software for various platforms.

But recently my curiosity has got the best of me and im starting to wonder about hardware and how to make it.

I'm pretty good with Boolean math and logic math. and know the basic about logic circuits (in theory... but everything about logic boards and circuits i´ve made on software or paper never made one for real).

the only real hardware stuff i have touched are really computer parts, i have putted together a hole computer... but never "made" anything by myself.

i do like real challenges, and get bored easily with really basic stuff like turning on a led etc.

So what would be a good project for a beginner to start with.. i was thinking of a calculator or maybe something simpler but interesting (interesting enough so it can get my attention because if something bores me i tend to stop it).

Eventually after making this project and some others i would like to be able to create my own thing start to get creative. i don't know basic stuff like being able to create a toy catapult that activates with a remote... i don't really know where i want to go with this, but as a software engineer i would like to know hardware too!

Thank You for your help in advance!

Comment: If questiins are exact matches would it not be a good idea to quote some references. This is expected of answerers when they mention material when passing. It's far easier for somebody who has done the due diligence to simply quiote thje outcome of their labours than for someone el;se to guess what terms may produce a match.

Comment: @ Ponchotg - I'd suggest you start with something so simple that it is dead easy to get going and so you can then see how it works and cam modify its actions. Nothing like some instant response to light the fires :-). I'd suggest a basic LED flasher and a simple siren. 2 x 555's will f-give you a very realistic traffic police siren *from NZ anyway). 1 x 74C14 / HEF 40106 / MC14584 - all hex Schnmitt inverters and som Rs Cs transistors LEDs and a small speaker can do wonders. Add a CD4017 and stuff happens. Add a=n Mc34063 and a few small inductors (say 100 uH) and ...!! :-)

Comment: [40106 Schmitt inverter data sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Philips%20Semiconductor%20PDFs/HEF40106B.pdf) you'd be UTTERLY amazed what you can build with these. Flashers, sirens, switching regulators, water level detectors, Audio to PWM, audio amplifiers !!!, more. |[LM324 - get some!](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM%2FLM324.pdf), [CD4017](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf) - sequencer, controller, .. . .[MC34063](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) convert any DC voltage to any voltage using ANY topology :-). 55 cents/1 Digikey

Comment: AND join this site [http://www.piclist.com](http://www.piclist.com) and ask all the beginner questions you want. Lots of advice. Many helpful people. Plus me :-).

Comment: Absurd to close this as an "exact duplicate" of the Arduino question, because nothing in this question is specific to micro-controllers.  While a micro-controller project is *one* candidate, it's only *one of many* possibilities.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, it could also be closed as not constructive, this is something we have discussed in chat before, and it is a very good medium for discussion project ideas, but they are generally considered not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, why not when it is an exact match have the user click to the original and read the information there?

Comment: @Kortuk - if you want to close it as not constructive, then say that.  But don't try to claim as justification something that is blatantly untrue: this is **NOT** a duplicate of the Arduino question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, it is very similar. That question does not guarantee that it is arduino, it is a user asking what to do as a seasoned programmer, he just included his prior research that had led him to arduino. It is a very very similar question, if not an exact duplicate. This question is also not constructive, I was not giving that as a guard for exact duplicate but it is a huge waste of time to argue about the close reason of a question when it is going to be closed with either outcome.

Comment: @ - The link was too big for me to see (assuming it was there before) :-). It didn't occur to me to look at the top of the question and it seems less than obvious now that that link is actually to an existing question. (I can NOW see that it is, but ...).  | The two questions appear to me (WWIK?) to be quite different. The answer I gave in the comments seemed to ne (WWIK) to be what he wanted but the other question was highly Arudino oriented. Whatever WWIK. Happy New Year 2:35h to go here, Last foot ...

Comment: @Kortuk - the "Arduino" question is only about micro-controllers, while this question has no such constraint.  As such claiming that as an "exact duplicate" is absurd - it completely ignores the subject of actual electronic circuitry by constraining to the possibilities to a packaged platform for software.  Not caring if the stated reason for a close is accurate or not is a gross failure in the running of the site - it gives the impression that actual facts are irrelevant.  Is that the sort of site you wish to have?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest grabbing a microcontroller starter kit of some sort - whilst running through the basic tutorials you will probably get many ideas of things you would like to try (plus have a little better idea of what may be involved)

The Arduino platform is any easy introduction into the world of microcontrollers, but if you want a real challenge it maybe better to start directly with the native tools.

Microchip make some good starter kits - something like the [PICKit3 Debug Express](http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductSearch.aspx?Keywords=DV164131) comes with a small 18F demo board and programmer/debugger that can be used for future projects.
If you would like a more powerful microcontroller, then the 32-bit [PIC32 starter kit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2615&dDocName=en532453) is well worth checking out.

For projects consider things like (when you get past the initial tutorials):
A digital clock, small line following robot, frequency counter using CCP module/comparator and display on LCD, simple tone generation, movement (e.g. human presence) detector, LED matrix/cube, IR remote control, serial communications with other micros/PC (SPI/UART/I2C)

Good luck!